# useContext error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

In my simple react project, I'm trying to implement useContext. But it is showing me error.

Context.js file -

```
import { createContext } from "react";
    
    const Info = createContext()
    function Provider(){
        const name = 'Arko'
        return(
            <Info.Provider value={{name}}></Info.Provider>
        )
    }
    export {Provider}
    export default Info
```

Contx.js file -

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import Info  from "../components2/context";

function Contx(){
    const hi = useContext(Info)
    return(
        <div>{hi.name}</div>
    )
}

export default Contx
```

App.js file -

```
import Contx from './components/contx';
import { Provider } from './components2/context';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Provider>
        <Contx/>
      </Provider>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error rendered on the screen -

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfo5e.png)

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Please help to solve it.

I am trying to display 'Arko' on screen but it is showing error.